# Google sheets compare 2 fields on a different sheet and return one based on criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 different Google Sheets.  Master Sales & Projections.  On Master Sales I have 2 columns, Expected & Billed which has data broken down by billing weeks.

I need Sheet 2 to grab the data from the cell that not 0 since we are trying to track total sales for the month (expected & actual) and then at the end of the month we would have the real billed numbers.

Potato example below

Sheet 1

```
   A        B  
1 Expect  Billed  
2 $123    $145  
3 $145    $155  
4 $156    $0  
5 $132    $0
```

What Sheet 2 should look like

```
  A      B
1 Week1  $145  
2 Week2  $155  
3 Week3  $156  
4 Week4  $132
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will arrange for the week numbers, in B1 please try:

```
={query(Sheet1!A2:B5,"select B where B<>0",0);query(Sheet1!A2:B5,"select A where B=0",0)}
```